# Selecting only element not in multiple tables

Tags: sql

I need help creating a query that will select the one animal in my "Animals" table that doesn't show up in my "events" table.

This is where I start off but I don't know where to go from here:

select * from Animal
where Event_ID=

I posted the tables for reference

Animals:
[image: animal table]

Events:
[image: event table]

Animal_Event:
[image: animal_event table]

Comment: There appears to be no relationship between those tables.

Comment: Looks like this is SQL-Server so tagging with the RDMS would help. Also, providing the example data in text, as well as the desired output, also in text, will help us help you.

Comment: As George has said, plus actually telling us the names of the tables as well.

Comment: Do you mean: "doesn't show up in animal_event table"? Show what output you expect. Maybe: `SELECT * FROM Animals WHERE Animal_ID NOT IN (SELECT Animal_ID FROM Animal_Event);`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something along these lines:

```
proc sql;
create table xyz as
select * from

(select distinct x as q from one) as a left join

(select distinct x as w from two) as b  
on a.q = b.w
where b.w = "";


quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
-- Select all fields from Animals table
-- where Animal_ID not in Animal_Event table.
SELECT X.*
FROM Animals AS X
WHERE A.Animal_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT Y.Animal_ID
    FROM Animal_Event AS Y
    GROUP BY Y.Animal_ID
    )
```